# How to detect if consumer was already in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataset that contains information if a consumer gave a recommendation or not:

```py
data = {'customer_id': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'recommend': [0, 1, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I would like to know if a customer gave 0 recommendation in the past. Desired output would be:

```py
data = {'customer_id': [1, 2, 1, 3], 'recommend': [0, 1, 1, 0], 'past': [0, 0, 1, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

How can I do it please?

Comment: You can leave the `past` with an empty array. When the user gives 0 recommendations add the value 0 in the array.

Comment: Accepted solution is correct in real data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function per groups with shifting and cumulative max in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['past'] = (df['recommend'].eq(0)
                             .groupby(df['customer_id'])
                             .transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=False).cummax())
                             .astype(int))

print (df)

   customer_id  recommend  past
0            1          0     0
1            2          1     0
2            1          1     1
3            3          0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by first adding a new column with your condition (`recommend == 0`) and then using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cummax.html) to obtain the wanted `past` column. Finally, drop the temporary column created.

Code:

```
df['equal_zero'] = (df['recommend'] == 0).astype(int)
df['past'] = df.groupby('customer_id')['equal_zero'].shift(1).cummax().fillna(0)
df = df.drop(columns=['equal_zero'])
```

Result:

```
  customer_id   recommend   past
0           1           0    0.0
1           2           1    0.0
2           1           1    1.0
3           3           0    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `'past'` is a boolean, (1 if a customer gave a zero in the past, 0 else).

Here is a one-line solution :

```py
df['past'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if len(df[(df.customer_id == x.customer_id) & (df.index < x.name) & (df.recommend == 0)]) > 0 else 0, axis=1)
```

If `'past'` is a count value :

```py
df['past'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(df[(df.customer_id == x.customer_id) & (df.index < x.name) & (df.recommend == 0)]), axis=1)
```